# lxml cssselect Parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing, css-selectors, lxml

I have a document with the following data:

```
<div class="ds-list">
    <b>1. </b> 
    A domesticated carnivorous mammal 
    <i>(Canis familiaris)</i> 
    related to the foxes and wolves and raised in a wide variety of breeds.
</div>
```

And I want to get everything within the class `ds-list` (without `<b>` and `<i>` tags). Currently my code is `doc.cssselect('div.ds-list')`, but all this picks up is the newline before the `<b>`. How can I get this to do what I want it to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the `text_content` method?:

```
import lxml.html as lh
content='''\
<div class="ds-list">
    <b>1. </b> 
    A domesticated carnivorous mammal 
    <i>(Canis familiaris)</i> 
    related to the foxes and wolves and raised in a wide variety of breeds.
</div>'''
doc=lh.fromstring(content)
for div in doc.cssselect('div.ds-list'):
    print(div.text_content())
```

yields

```
1.  
A domesticated carnivorous mammal 
(Canis familiaris) 
related to the foxes and wolves and raised in a wide variety of breeds.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.cssselect("div.ds-list").text_content()
```