# How lxml with cssselect get text

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

Example:

```
html='<div class="a"><input type="text" value="bla bla bla">some text</div>'
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
a=doc.cssselect("div.a")
print a[0].text
```

This print empty string...
How i get "some text"?

Comment: Hrm, sorry, that's the inverse, but the answer to your question is right there. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [lxml cssselect Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4909811) instead then.

Comment: As @MartijnPieters mentioned use print a[0].text will actually print the text